# precision in calculators

Tags: calculator

The (square root of 0.99) minus 1 is

> -0.005012562893380035 according to Java 8 on 64-bit Linux.
>
> -0.005012562893380040 according to LibreOffice on 64-bit Linux.
>
> -0.005012562 according to the Sharp EL-W535 calculator.

This is disappointing because at the 1 billionth decimal place the calculator is wrong because it should be a 3 (given that ...28 should round to ...3).

I bought this calculator because it has a very wide display and the LCD itself is capable of displaying more digits but unfortunately it only showed billionths. I can live with that but what I dislike that the digit is actually wrong. What accounts for this? Are such machines typically 32 bit or is there some other explanation? Even if it were a 32 bit machine, that is a poor excuse because it should be possible for even an 8 bit machine to provide the same answer as a 64 bit machine (albeit with more complicated software).

Comment: Some people truncate by convention. The billionth digit won't matter to engineers, and the decimal representation will always be wrong to mathematicians, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: It's true most calculator users will not care about billionths. In my case I care because I am using a calculator to provide hardcoded answers to some software tests and it is more convenient to use the calculator than a spreadsheet. Billionths is not a lot to ask for.

Comment: I use CASIO FX-570ES Plus as well as a lot of my students it costs about €16 and calculates derivatives and integrals. Your calculation result was displayed as $\dfrac{3 \sqrt{11}}{10}-1$ and then I converted it in decimals. I strongly recommend this or other CASIO calculators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the range outside which numbers are displayed in scientific notation, and then, it would most likely be something like -5.012562893E-3 in this case. Set up with J 1 4, according to the point "SET UP Menu" in the [user manual](http://office.manualsonline.com/manuals/mfg/sharp/elw535.html?p=2).

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute $\sqrt{1+x}-1$ with small $x$ (in your example $x=-0.01$). The direct computation is unstable because of catastrophic cancellation (think about $x=10^{-30}$ or so)! A stable version for small $x$ is
$$\sqrt{1+x}-1 = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x}+1}$$